# LAMP questions please help

Tags: apache2, lamp

I am running a LAMP stack on an Ubuntu server version 12.04 on digitalocean and have used filezilla to upload files. I uploaded them to var/www and for whatever reason the pictures that I have tried to upload do not display. I am a complete noob when it comes to linux and internet programming. I have double checked the html and that isn't the issue.
I was wondering if anyone has had this issue and figured out how to resolve it.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It is likely a permissions problem. What are the permissions of the files ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to access the main html page (ie, index.html or the like) or any other page, and the pictures are under the /var/www directory, then it would be a permissions problem. What kinds of errors are you getting? No permission? Not found? Login to your server via ssh (`ssh USERNAME@SERVERIP` or run PuTTY from Windows) and try the following in order until you run into a problem or/and STOP when the problem is fixed:

1. Ensure you can access any files on your webserver. Does the index page come up? If not, you have LAMP incorrectly set up. Go through the tutorials again or post another question here.
2. Ensure your files are even there. Do `ls /var/www` and make sure you see the files you are trying to upload. If you do see your files, skip to step 6.
3. Re-upload your files using ftp and either an admin's or the www-data user's credentials. Try viewing your images again.
4. If uploading worked and you see your files if you `ls /var/www`, skip to step 6. Manually add the files using scp if on Ubuntu:

   `scp /path/to/picture.png USERNAME@SERVERIP:/var/www/`
5. If the files are STILL not there or if using Windows, manually add the files via external media (ie, flashdrive).
6. Run `chmod 755 /var/www -R`. That will allow all files to be read by anybody, but only allow the owner of /var/www to change the files. Try viewing your pictures again.
7. You may have some other permission issues if this doesn't work. Do `ls -lR /var/www` and show us the output.

The only other thing I can thing of would be some kind of filter blocking pictures from being accessed directly. Let me know if this helped you!